# Only get stdout and stderr without actually running the command

Tags: command-line, bash, git

So I wanted to make a script that automatically uploads all my changes to github. I managed everything, except for one thing. I want to log the stdout and stderr from the github commands, without actually adding, committing, or pushing the file to github. I want to do it after the output has been written into the log file. Code is below:

```
function fnSave {
  fnLogWriter "" 1
  fnLogWriter "git add stdout:"
  git add -A >> ${myLogFileWithPath} 2>&1
  fnLogWriter "" 1
  fnLogWriter "git commit stdout:"
  git commit -m ${myCommitMessage} >> ${myLogFileWithPath} 2>&1
  fnLogWriter "" 1
  fnLogWriter "git push stdout:"
  git push -u origin ${myCurrentBranch} >> ${myLogFileWithPath} 2>&1
}
```

Don't worry about the fnLogWriter, it's a custom function. The paths are correct and everything. When the file creates, the log text below git -add is in the files, but due to it uploading first, the rest is not on github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the git commands have a `--dry-run` option, so you can get output only like this:

```
function fnSave {
  fnLogWriter "" 1
  fnLogWriter "git add stdout:"
  git add --dry-run -A >> ${myLogFileWithPath} 2>&1
  fnLogWriter "" 1
  fnLogWriter "git commit stdout:"
  git commit --dry-run -m ${myCommitMessage} >> ${myLogFileWithPath} 2>&1
  fnLogWriter "" 1
  fnLogWriter "git push stdout:"
  git push --dry-run -u origin ${myCurrentBranch} >> ${myLogFileWithPath} 2>&1
}
```

Comment: However, without actually adding the files, the commit dry run would be different, and without actually committing, the push dry run will also be different.

Comment: You're right. For this to work, each step will have to be done incrementally, so first `add --dry-run`, then add for real, `commit --dry-run`, commit for real etc.

Comment: Oh, nice thanks! Just realized I can't really use it in my case, but it's still something I should know

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging, despite it not being applicable to your particular usecase.